# Which edition of Salesforce do you get during free trial?

Tags: editions

I am testing some calls using the partner WSDL via a .NET application and everything works well.

I need to test calling the API against other Salesforce accounts so I signed up for a free 30 day trial with Salesforce but the API seems to be turned off.

Questions

1. In Salesforce where can you see what edition you have?
2. In Salesforce where can you see if the API is enabled? Is it on a per install or per user basis?
3. Which edition do you get during your free trial?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers:

> In Salesforce where can you see what edition you have?

Go to Setup -> Company Information.
In this page, see Organization Edition field value.

> In Salesforce where can you see if the API is enabled? Is it on a per install or per user basis?

Go to Setup --> Manage Users --> click on the user link whose credentials you are using for connecting Salesforce.

In the user details, click on the profile.

In the Profile details, verify `API Enabled` is selected.

> Which edition do you get during your free trial?

Verify the same, in the first answer

Answer (score 0):

> In Salesforce where can you see what edition you have?

In Classic, your browser's title bar usually tells you, e.g. Salesforce - Enterprise Edition. Alternatively, you can go to Company Information in Setup, and you'll see the Organization Edition field.

> In Salesforce where can you see if the API is enabled? Is it on a per install or per user basis?

Both. The org must have it in order for users to use the API at all, and each user must also have API Enabled in order to use the API for their account. I don't believe there's an easy place to tell if your org has API access, but you can click on Help to contact support; they can tell you definitively.

> Which edition do you get during your free trial?

You can get a free trial for almost any edition these days, but you need to find the correct form. Depending on the link you used, you might have any of the current offerings that salesforce has. If you want to sign up for a *specific* trial edition, but can't find the link, contact Sales.